Docker Compose container name hex string prefix
I have a Compose project using Compose version 2.27.1, named myproj. Sporadically, when I do an up, I end up with certain container names being prefixed with a random 12-character hexadecimal string (plus underscore).
E.g.
$ docker compose up -d
$ docker ps ...

NAMES
myproj-alpha-1
myproj-beta-1
myproj-gamma-1
d87fed842480_myproj-delta-1   <--- ???
myproj-epsilon-1
myproj-zeta-1

What is that? How can I prevent that?
Docker Compose documentation about this behaviour is non-existent.

Do you have a [mcve]?  That hex string isn't part of the current directory name, is it?

No it's not. Also, the hex string is different every time. As I said, it happens randomly so I haven't been able to reproduce it consistently as of now.

Can you add the docker-compose file (remove the secrets and business specifics) @DanieleRepici

It's a complex project with several compose files, 80+ services, 1.5k+ LOC, volumes, dependencies and whatnot. I don't think it would be of much benefit to share. This clearly seems an intrinsic behaviour of docker compose rather than being project-specific so I was just hoping someone knew the answer regardless, the same way if someone asked me "why does compose prepend 'myproj' to all my containers" I could tell them "because that's your compose project name and compose does that" I wouldn't have to ask them their compose file
